# How to hierarchically append "composed" elements based on elements' attributes using D3 d3js?

Tags: d3.js, svg

I am using D3.js and I have a list of elements with an attribute describing categories like this one:

```
var nodes = [
{id:"a", cat:[0,1]},
{id:"b", cat:[0]},
{id:"c", cat:[0,1,2]}];
```

Each element is a multi-circle-node positioned by a force layout. The number of categories of an element defines the number of circles that will represent it.

[image: Nodes]

The "solution" I have for now is to create layers for each category. The force layout handles the list of data. The layers handle the svg elements.
Each layer is an  element.

- In the `<g class="layer2">` I draw a circle for node c, with radius = 9;
- In the `<g class="layer1">` I draw circles for nodes a and c, with radius = 6;
- In the `<g class="layer0">` I draw circles for nodes a, b and c, with radius = 3;

The problem is that each data element is being represented by separated circles in separated layers.

How can we represent each element by a group of circles like this:

```
    <g class="node" id="a">
       <circle>... <circle>...
    </g>
   <g class="node" id="b">
       <circle>...
    </g>
   <g class="node" id="c">
       <circle>... <circle>... <circle>...
    </g>
```

Is it possible to use something hierarchically in D3 style of code like:

```
svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("id", function(d){return d.id;}
    //for each category on this node              
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", function(){ return (cat+1)*3;});
```

A solution like this would be the best option.

Or do I have to create the elements `<g class="node" id="...">`  separately, `selectAll(".node")` and then link them to the data (node list)?

Comment: Thanks for approving, however I think, that Gerardo Furtado's answer is more detailed.

Comment: Thank you so much, guys! I've changed it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that you just need nested selections:

```
var groups = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(nodes)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("id", function(d) {
    return d.id
  });

var circles = groups.selectAll(null)
  .data(function(d) {
    return d.cat
  })
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  //etc...
```

This is a demo showing it, with your `nodes` data:

```js
var nodes = [{
  id: "a",
  cat: [0, 1]
}, {
  id: "b",
  cat: [0]
}, {
  id: "c",
  cat: [0, 1, 2]
}];

var colors = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

var svg = d3.select("svg");

var groups = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(nodes)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("id", function(d) {
    return d.id
  })
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    return "translate(" + (50 + 100 * i) + ",75)";
  });

var circles = groups.selectAll(null)
  .data(function(d) {
    return d.cat
  })
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", function(d) {
    return 10 + (d * 10)
  })
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return colors(i)
  });

circles.sort(function(a, b) {
  return d3.descending(a, b)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

If you inspect your SVG, you're gonna see this:

```
<svg>
    <g id="a" transform="translate(50,75)">
        <circle r="30" style="fill: rgb(31, 119, 180);"></circle>
        <circle r="20" style="fill: rgb(255, 127, 14);"></circle>
    </g>
    <g id="b" transform="translate(150,75)">
        <circle r="30" style="fill: rgb(31, 119, 180);"></circle>
    </g>
    <g id="c" transform="translate(250,75)">
        <circle r="30" style="fill: rgb(31, 119, 180);"></circle>
        <circle r="20" style="fill: rgb(255, 127, 14);"></circle>
        <circle r="10" style="fill: rgb(44, 160, 44);"></circle>
    </g>
</svg>
```

PS: I'm sorting the circles (have a look at the bottom of the code) to bring the smaller circles to the top, making them visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
svg.selectAll(".node")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("id", function(d){return d.id;})  
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(function(d) {return d.cat}) // <-- bind cat data
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", function(d) {
        //set radius 
  });
```